# comparing month,year parts of util.Date in dropdown list

Tags: jsp, drop-down-menu, comparison, el

In my web app,a customer object has fields related to credit card info

```
public class Customer {
    ...
    private String ccType;
    private Date ccExpirationDate;
    ...
}
```

In the jsp page I am providing drop down lists to select credit card type,expiration month,expiration year.
I want to check if a customer exists in session and if so his credit cardtype and month,year parts of expiration date matches any of the options in drop down list,then those options are shown as selected .

In contextInitialized() method of a class implementing ServletContextListener ,I created maps as below..

```
Map<String,String> cardtypes = new TreeMap<String,String>();
        cardtypes.put("M0", "MasterCard");
        cardtypes.put("D0", "Discover");
...
Map<String,String> expiryMonths = new TreeMap<String,String>();
        expiryMonths.put("01", "January");
        expiryMonths.put("02", "February");
...
Map<String,String> expiryYears = new TreeMap<String,String>();
for(int i=2011;i<2030;i++){
            String year = Integer.toString(i+1);
            expiryYears.put(year,year);
        }
...
sc.setAttribute("ccyears", expiryYears);
sc.setAttribute("ccmonths", expiryMonths);
sc.setAttribute("cctypes", cardtypes);
```

I tried this.

```
<tr>
<td>
    <select id="creditCardType" title="select card type" name="creditCardType">
        <c:forEach var="cctype" items="${cctypes }">
            <option ${not empty customer and customer.ccType == cctype.key ? 'selected':'' } value="${cctype.key }">${cctype.value }</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Expiration Date</td>
<td> 
 <select id="cardexpiryMonth" name="cardexpiryMonth">
    <c:forEach var="ccmonth" items="${ccmonths }">
            <option ${not empty customer and customer.ccExpirationDate.month == ccmonth.key ? 'selected':'' } value="${ccmonth.key }">${ccmonth.value }</option>
    </c:forEach>
 </select>
</td>
<td>
<select id="cardexpiryYear" name="cardexpiryYear">
    <c:forEach var="ccyear" items="${ccyears }">
            <option ${not empty customer and customer.ccExpirationDate.year == ccyear.key ? 'selected':'' } value="${ccyear.key }">${ccyear.value }</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

This works for creditcard type ,which is shown as customer's card type selected.But the customer's  expiration month and year are not shown selected..Is the failure due to int-string comparison?Is there a way to correct this problem?

(I know util.Date's getMonth(),getYear() are deprecated..but could think of no other way to do this using EL)

any help appreciated

thanks

mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to months, there are 2 causes:

- [`Date#getMonth()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getMonth%28%29) is 0-based. January is 0, February is 1, etc.
- You've prefixed the month map key with 0. A value of 01 is not the same as 1. So it'll only match a month of November and December on dropdown options October and November respectively.

For years, there is 1 cause:

- [`Date#getYear()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear%28%29) is 1900-based. 2011 returns 111, 2012 returns 112, etc. A value of 111 is not the same as 2011, so it'll never match.

So, fix the code accordingly:

```
    expiryMonths.put("1", "January");
    expiryMonths.put("2", "February");
    // ...
```

and in EL

```
 (customer.ccExpirationDate.month + 1) == ccmonth.key
```

and

```
 (customer.ccExpirationDate.year + 1900) == ccyear.key
```

*(You'll now probably understand better why `Date` is a total epic failure and is been deprecated)*